# Operations with user-defined physical types in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, user-defined-types

I am a beginner in VHDL and was doing some operations with user defined type "distance" as declared below:

```
entity metric is
type DISTANCE is range 0 to 1000000000 
units 
nm;
mm = 10E6 nm;
cm = 10 mm;
m = 100 cm;
km = 10E3 m;
inch = 25400000 nm;
foot = 12 inch;
yard = 3 foot;
mile = 1760 yard;
end units;
end metric;
```

In the architecture I declared variables of distance type and tried some operations with an integer value.

```
architecture test of metric is
 begin
  P1 : process
   variable res1, res2 : DISTANCE ;
  begin
   res1 := 10  * (10 nm);
   res2 := 10 / (10 nm);
   wait;
  end process;
end test;
```

The code compiles for res1 but for res2 following errors occur -

> No feasible entries for infix operator "/"
>
> Bad right hand side(infix expression) in variable assignment

Can anybody explain why multiplication works but division fails in above case?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's really nothing it could automatically do here. What would the units be for `1/distance`?

Comment: @jeff : logically, wavenumber! If the OP wants this to work he could declare wavenumber types and overload the `/` operator... Or at present, `10 nm / 10` ought to work... Formally, multiplication is commutative but division isn't.

Answer (score 1):

If you were to look in IEEE Std 1076-2008, 9.2.7 Multiplying operators:

[image: Multiplying Operators]

You'd find that division by a physical type other than with a left operand of the same physical type is not a predefined.

You need to define a "/" function to overload the division operator for  your physical type or you you need to convert the left hand expression to your physical type. Also note the result is an integer describing the relationship between the two operands of the physical type.